# cronometros en varios div dinamicos con js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

que tal? estoy realizando un modulo para una pantalla en cocina donde se puede visualizar las comandas que envian desde otro sistema, las comandas aparecen con normalidad y ejecuto un interval cada 3 segundos para que realice la consulta a la bd y se actualice automaticamente las comandas.

lo que necesito ahora y no se si sea posible con js es un cronometro para cada comanda, que comience cuando se crea la misma.

este es el codigo del modulo.

```
<div class="zonas" style="margin-top: 70px;">   
    <h2>SELECCIONE ZONA</h2>
    <?
    $query = "select id, nombre from ubicaciones where tipo = 2 order by nombre";
    $result = qry($query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <a data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-b" onClick="seleccionarzona(<?=$row['id']?>)"><?=$row['nombre']?></a>
    <?
    }
    ?>
    <br class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-b categoria">
</div>

<div class="vistaordenes" style="display: none">
</div>
```

este es el codigo js que imprime las comandas:

var idzona = 0;
    var pause = 1;

```
function seleccionarzona(id){
    idzona = id;

    $(".zonas").hide();
    $(".vistaordenes").show();
    pause = 0;
    ordenes();

}

function zonas() {
    var idzona = 0;
    var pause = 1;
    $(".vistaordenes").hide();
    $(".zonas").show();
}


function ordenes() {

  setInterval(function(){

    cargarordenes(idzona);

  }, 3000);


}

function cargarordenes(id) {

    if(pause==0){

        var parameters = {
            "idzona": id
            };


    $.ajax({

        data:  parameters,
        url:   'cargarordenes.php',
        type:  'post',
           success:  function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var ToJson = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(ToJson);
            var containerordenes = $(".vistaordenes");
            containerordenes.empty();

            var output = `<div class="row show-grid">`;

            var article = ''; 

            var numColumns = 3;

            var rowcount = 0;

            var timerH = 0;

            var timerM = 0;

            var timerS = 0;

            var timerIni = timerH+':'+timerM+':'+timerS;

            totalItems = ToJson[0].length;

            ToJson[1].forEach(function(orden, index) {
                article += `<div class="col-md-4 orden-${orden.idorden}">
                                <article id="order${orden.idorden}" class="orden" style=" cursor: pointer; margin:10px;">
                                    <div style="padding: 20px; background-color: white; color: black; width:100%">
                                        <div>
                                            <div onclick="cerrarorden(${orden.idorden})">
                                            <h3>ORDEN: ${orden.numero}</h3>
                                            <h3>FECHA:&nbsp;${orden.fecha}</h3><h2>MESA:&nbsp;&nbsp;${orden.mesa}</h2>
                                            <h3 class"timer-title">TIEMPO:&nbsp;<span class="timer">${timerIni}</span></h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`;
                        for(var i=0; i<totalItems; i++){
                            var listo = ToJson[0][i].listo;
                            if (listo == 1) {
                                listo = 'text-decoration: line-through;';
                            }
                            if (orden.idorden == ToJson[0][i].idorden) {
                                    article += `<div>
                                                <li id='producto${ToJson[0][i].iditem}' style='font-size: 16px; ${listo}' onclick='productolisto(${ToJson[0][i].iditem})'>${ToJson[0][i].cantidad} X ${ToJson[0][i].item}</li><br>
                                                    ${ToJson[0][i].ingredientesopcionales}&nbsp;${ToJson[0][i].opciones}
                                                </div>`;                                            
                            }
                        }
                                article += `</div>
                                </article>
                            </div>`;
                            rowcount++;
                            if (rowcount % numColumns == 0) {
                                article += `</div><div class="row show-grid">`;
                            }
            });

            output += article;

            output += `</div>`;

            containerordenes.append(output);

           }
     });

    pause = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: De entrada, la forma en que armas el HTML de la comanda no es muy amigable para agregar eventos o funciones. Al menos el contenedor del cronómetro se debe crear con algo como `var crono = document.createElement('span');` e ir agregando las propiedades necesarias, incluyendo una función que inicie el cronómetro y llame a otra función para actualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a poner un **ejemplo donde creo 5 relojes, uno cada 3 segundos**, con ***Vainilla JS***, *cuidado que tengo una función `$()` similar a la de jQuery, que yo no usaré*.

#### Ejemplo 1. Relojes parados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inicialmente se van creando relojes. Van a estar parados para que se vea en que momento fueron añadidos a la página.
El ejemplo muestra como se crean los relojes y se añaden a la página. Hay tres grupos de funciones:

1. GUI. Son funciones auxiliares para manipular elementos el dom.
2. Clocks. Son las que se usa para controlar los tiempos y generar los relojes.
3. Times. Son funciones auxiliares para generar una hora en formato 'hh:mm:ss'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding: 5% 12%;
        }
        .buttons,
        .clocks {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .buttons {
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .clocks div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            border : 1px solid blue;
            margin : 1rem;
            padding: .5rem
        }
        .clocks div span {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
        <!-- añado 5 relojes con un intervalo de 3 segundos -->
        <button onclick="runClocks(3, 5)">
            Run Clocks
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clocks" id="clocks"></div>
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock_number = 0;
        
        /**
         * GUI
         * 
         */
        function $(element_id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(element_id);
        }
        function setText(element_id, content)
        {
            $(element_id).innerText = content;
        }

        /**
         * Clocks
         * 
         */
        function addClock()
        {
            clock_number++;

            const clock_id = 'id_' + clock_number;
            const time_id  =  clock_id + '_time';


            let clock_text = 'Clock ' + clock_number 
                + ': <span id="' + time_id + '"></span>';

            let container  = $('clocks');
            let content    = document.createElement('div');
            content.idName = clock_id;
            content.innerHTML = clock_text;
            container.appendChild(content);

                
            const time = getTime(); // str hh:mm:ss
            setText(time_id, time);
            
        }
        function runClocks(interval_in_seconds, max_clocks)
        {
            let counter = 0;

            const clocks = setInterval(
                () => {
                    counter++;

                    if (counter === interval_in_seconds) {
                        counter = 0;
                        if (max_clocks > 0) {
                            addClock();
                            max_clocks--;
                        }
                    }
                },
                1000
            );
        }

        /**
         * Times
         * 
         */
        function fillTwoDigitsPositions(number)
        {
            return (number < 10)
                ? '0' + number
                : number;
        }
        function getTime()
        {
            const date  = new Date();
            let hours   = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getHours());
            let minutes = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getMinutes());
            let seconds = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getSeconds());

            return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Ejemplo 2. Relojes funcionando

Evoluciona el primer ejemplo, de forma que los relojes funcionen. Se ve como se van añadiendo pero todos marcan el mismo tiempo, supongo que lo ideal sería mostrar en cada uno el tiempo trascurrido (elapsed time) desde su creación.

Primero, los cambios sobre el primer código:

> 1. Añadí la variable global:

```
var cloks_time_ids = [];
```

*Donde almaceno la id de la caja de tiempo de cada reloj creado, para ir actualizando las horas...*

> 2. Añado la id de la caja de tiempo de cada reloj segun los voy creando. Dentro de `addClock()`:

```
cloks_time_ids.push(time_id);
```

> 3. Elimino el código que ponía la hora en cada reloj cuando se creaba, dentro de `addClock()`. Esto lo hace ahora en la función que va
>      actualizando los relojes:

```
//const time = getTime(); // str hh:mm:ss
//setText(time_id, time);
```

*Lo he dejado comentado para que se vea mejor.*

> 4. Añado la función para actualizar los relojes:

```
function updateClocks() {
    console.log('updateClocks()', cloks_time_ids); // HACK:

    const total_times = cloks_time_ids.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < total_times; i++) {

        const time_id = cloks_time_ids[i];
        const time = getTime(); // str hh:mm:ss
        setText(time_id, time);
    }
}
```

*Recorre todas las ids de caja de tiempo creadas cada segundo para actualizar los tiempos, puedes verlo con el `console.log()` que he dejado.*

> 5. Llamada a la función actual, dentro de `setInterval()`:

```
const clocks = setInterval(
    () => {
        counter++;

        if (counter === interval_in_seconds) {
            counter = 0;
            if (max_clocks > 0) {
                addClock();
                max_clocks--;
            }
        }

        updateClocks();
    },
    1000
);
```

Código final (ejecutar prueba a pantalla completa):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding: 5% 12%;
        }
        .buttons,
        .clocks {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .buttons {
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .clocks div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            border : 1px solid blue;
            margin : 1rem;
            padding: .5rem
        }
        .clocks div span {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button onclick="runClocks(3, 5)">
            Run Clocks
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clocks" id="clocks"></div>
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock_number = 0;
        var cloks_time_ids = [];
        
        /**
         * GUI
         * 
         */
        function $(element_id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(element_id);
        }
        function setText(element_id, content)
        {
            $(element_id).innerText = content;
        }

        /**
         * Clocks
         * 
         */
        function addClock()
        {
            clock_number++;

            const clock_id = 'id_' + clock_number;
            const time_id  =  clock_id + '_time';


            let clock_text = 'Clock ' + clock_number 
                + ': <span id="' + time_id + '"></span>';

            let container  = $('clocks');
            let content    = document.createElement('div');
            content.idName = clock_id;
            content.innerHTML = clock_text;
            container.appendChild(content);

            cloks_time_ids.push(time_id);

                

            //const time = getTime(); // str hh:mm:ss
            //setText(time_id, time);
            
        }
        function runClocks(interval_in_seconds, max_clocks)
        {
            let counter = 0;

            const clocks = setInterval(
                () => {
                    counter++;

                    if (counter === interval_in_seconds) {
                        counter = 0;
                        if (max_clocks > 0) {
                            addClock();
                            max_clocks--;
                        }
                    }

                    updateClocks();
                },
                1000
            );
        }
        function updateClocks() {
            console.log('updateClocks()', cloks_time_ids); // HACK:

            const total_times = cloks_time_ids.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < total_times; i++) {
                
                const time_id = cloks_time_ids[i];
                const time = getTime(); // str hh:mm:ss
                setText(time_id, time);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Times
         * 
         */
        function fillTwoDigitsPositions(number)
        {
            return (number < 10)
                ? '0' + number
                : number;
        }
        function getTime()
        {
            const date  = new Date();
            let hours   = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getHours());
            let minutes = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getMinutes());
            let seconds = fillTwoDigitsPositions(date.getSeconds());

            return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```